# Python - First Interface with a Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, accounting

I have spent the last six months learning python as a way to automate my working environment.  So far I have automated data extraction and report downloading from various web-based sources through the use of webcrawlers, interacted with excel files, created visual representations of data through matplotlib, and removed almost all the monotony from bank reconciliation.

I now come to a new task which takes up a large amount of my daily workload.  We use an accounts program called Sage 50 Accounts.  I effectively want to begin to learn how to manipulate the data contained within this program so that my daily thought patterns can be put into Python code.

Because this hasn't been done, there's no pre-made API.  So my question is:
When wishing to interact with a new program through Python, how does a programmer begin such an inquiry?

Please accept that this question is only vague and general because I'm incredibly new to such a task.

Comment: "how does a programmer begin such an inquiry" is way too broad of a question here. The task is also borderline impossible, especially for a new programmer, if the program doesn't already offer an API in any way, be it for C programming or a REST interface. If there is such an API, you write a python Wrapper for it; if there isn't, you're out of luck unless you want to hack the binaries...

Comment: Whatever's involved, even the requirement of another language.  I would still appreciate a broad overview with key words that I could use to investigate and self-learn such a process.

Comment: That's extremely dependent on the specific type of API and thus still too broad. For a REST/SOAP or similar network based interface you'd just write a python class that makes the appropriate network requests and handles the responses; for a C interface you'd need to write and compile a python C module (the best way to learn how this works would probably be 1. reading the official docs and 2. reading code which does exactly that; e.g. PyQT which is a python Wrapper for QT). For APIs in other languages or for other types of interfaces (e.g. serialport) you'd of course need different solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SData](http://sdata.sage.com/) is Sage's general data access API layer and should suit your purposes.

Otherwise you might need to invest in or obtain a [Sage Development SDK](https://signon.sage.co.uk/?ReturnUrl=https://my.sage.co.uk/UK/Communities/Developers/sage-developers-programme/membership-at-a-glance.aspx).